# error while compiling a jar project maven eclipse

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I am trying to compile the jar project from kafka example from github (https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples)

After setting up the envirement and all the components(Kafka 2.11-1.1.0 & zookeeper , creating a topic and changing all the properties stuff) The project actually get a build success using maven 3.3.9 in eclipse oxygen but when I try the java -jar *******.jar I get the following error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/utils/ShutdownableThread
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.apex.examples.kafka.kafka2hdfs.TestConsumer.main(TestConsumer.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Here is the TestConsumer.java

```
package org.apache.apex.examples.kafka.kafka2hdfs;

public class TestConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Consumer consumerThread = new Consumer(KafkaProperties.TOPIC);
        consumerThread.start();
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post TestConsumer.java code @user

Comment: Please use actual Apache Git mirror https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/1.1/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples that is updated more recently than 7 years ago